# Replace cell value if containing specified words

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How is it possible to scan for words and replace the whole cell via command? 
I have the value

> ASUS MB Z270 D4 1151

or

> MB ASUS D4 Z270 1151

(word order doesn't matter)

And I want it to be:

> Motherboard - Asus Z270 DDR4 LGA1151

I want to do the same for 1000+ values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

Answer (score 0):

Hit <kbd>CTRL + H</kbd> for **Search & Replace**.